# getting a parameter from a callback request using node.js and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, twilio

I'm using the twilio API and node.js to successfully record and transcribe calls. I'm trying to implement a callback when a call is recorded. According to the twilio API, I specify my callback URL:

```
twiml.record({
    transcribe: false,
    maxLength: 30, //seconds to record
    recordingStatusCallback: 'http://[url]:3000/recorded'
  })
```

Per the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-recording-status-callback), I should receive some parameters back via POST, so I am logging the request and response:

```
app.post('/recorded', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req, res)
})
```

What I get back in the log is a couple of giant objects, and I don't see anything that looks like the parameters I'm expecting. I'm guessing I'm supposed to be constructing that post function differently to get the parameters I need, but i'm not sure how, and I don't see any documentation in Twilio or online that shows how a successful callback function is structured.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all add 'body-parser' module to your project.

```
npm install body-parser
```

And require it in the code:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
```

Now add it somewhere in the code before launching the server:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));  //this will add extracting of the body for every request to express server
```

After that, in your functions, where you are trying to find data, you can get it using such code:

```
app.post('/recorded', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);  //body of the request in javascript object format
})
```

Find more info about 'body-parser' module [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser).

Comment: Twilio sends data as url encoded form data, so you need the `urlencoded` middleware from bodyParser. I edited the answer for that. The attributes that you will receive in the callback are listed here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-recording-status-callback. You are probably interested in `req.body.RecordingUrl` for example.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I know it's sort of a language / environment specific use case, but it would be cool to add this example somewhere online